# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found IOT Simulate

Tags: python-3.x, azure-iot-hub

I am new to `Python` and trying to create sample iot-hub-python project [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted#create-a-simulated-device-app).

I tried to install `azure-iothub-device-client` and got it installed properly. But when I run `SimulateDevice.py` file, it gives an error.

> ImportError:
>   DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found for iothub_client.

I tried creating simple Hello World application. It worked fine. Also I have already installed Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: Which version of python is installed?The sample applications in the link need either Python 2.7.x or 3.5.x on your development machine. You can verify the current version of Python on your development machine using `python --version` or `python3 --version`.

Comment: Try installing the C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) - 14.10.25008 or
C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) - 14.10.25008 (according to your system version).

Comment: I am having python 3.7 and also installed C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) - 14.10.25008 but no luck

Comment: @Rutu, is there another version python installed on your development pc? And have you checked the `azure-iothub-device-client`  package had been installed successfully?